# Using dynamic value from Config File - XSLT Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, config

Input File:

```
<member>
<memberID>500</memberID>
<name>John</name>
<memberID>501</memberID>
<name>Mathew</name>
<memberID>502></memberID>
<name>Clark</name>
</member>
```

I am using an XSLT which looks like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:copy-of select="member[child::memberID/text()='500']"/>
```

Now, I need to use a config file or any other way to make this comparison with 500 dynamic i.e. In case in the config I make the value 501, the xslt should now compare with 501 instead of 500.

Any ideas on how to use the config file concept here in XSLT.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that's your input? One member element with multiple menmberIDs?

Answer (score 0):

You can read data from another file using the **document()** function. Another option is to pass a **parameter** to the XSLT stylesheet during runtime.